# apps.uses action not working

Tags: facebook, installation, facebook-opengraph

By default when user starts using app, a ticker used to get posted in timeline "x started is using this app". I not able to see such tickers. Also I manually tried sending a curl request to "https://graph.facebook.com/me/apps.uses" with access_token and website parameters when apps gets loaded. It returns {id:"xxxxx"} as response that means action is being called but its not getting updated in timeline. I tried to debug the response id in graph explorer that was also perfect.Social discovery is on and app is not in sandbox mode. Client want this ticker I had committed, its so easy to implement but now I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

You don't post those, they're automatically created by Facebook and surfaced in ticker / available for type 25 ads

Comment: So for normal apps (not falling under type 25 ads) how can we make this ticker visible. Or is there any parameters say for app having MAU > 1000 such tickers gets posted automatically. I tried installing app from 3 different users and in none of theirs friends ticker this ticker got visible. Rest all open graph activity are getting displayed fine.

Comment: I don't think those stories appear in ticker that often, they're more likely to be used for the units on the right column recommending games to friends of people who already play the game, etc